# Addressing a report on waseelah from al-Waqidi

Tags: authenticity

Is the following report authentic?

> Abdullah bin Qurt narrates :
>
> I then departed from the Masjid via Ethiopia Gate and said to myself, "I will commit a grave error if I fail to make salam at the tomb of Rasulullah, for I do not know whether or not I will see it again."
>
> So I went to the room where 'Aishah was sitting at the grave. 'Ali and al-'Abbas were also present with al-Husayn sitting in 'Ali's lap and al-Hasan in al-'Abbas's lap. They were reciting Suratul-An'am while 'Ali was reciting Surah Hud. I made salam to Rasulullah.
>
> 'Ali: O Ibn Qurt, are you going to Syria?
>
> Ibn Qurt: Yes, O cousin of Rasulullah. I think that once I reach there the two armies will already be deeply embroiled in fighting. They will see me coming without help or reinforcements. I really fear that they will become weak and frightened. I wish that I could reach them before they fight so that I can at least advise them and counsel them with patience.
>
> 'Ali: So what is stopping you from asking 'Umar to make du'a for you?.
>
> Ibn Qurt: I am well aware of all these virtues of 'Umar which you have mentioned, but in addition I would like your du'a and the du'a of al-'Abbas, the paternal uncle of Rasulullah, especially here at the noble tomb of Rasulullah.
>
> Al-'Abbas raised his hand in supplication. 'Ali, al-Hasan, al-Husayn, 'Aishah (and Hafsah and Umm Salamah who had also arrived) joined them. He prayed, "**O Allah, we seek intercession through this chosen Prophet and selected Messenger through whom Adam also sought intercerssion and then You forgave his error**. O Allah, make the road easy for 'Abdullah and fold up the long distances for him. Help the Sahabah of Your Prophet with victory. You are the Hearer of Du'a."
>
> He then said, "Go Abdullah, for it is unlikely that Allah will reject the du'a of 'Umar, 'Abbas, 'Ali, al-Hasan, and the wives of Rasulullah, especially when they have interceded through the best of all creation." (Al-Imam al-Waqidi, The Islamic Conquest of Syria, A Translation of Futuhusham: The Inspiring History of the Sahabah's Conquest of Syria, translated by Mawlana Sulayman al-Kindi [Ta-Ha Publishers Ltd., London 2005], Part 3: Al-Yarmuk, pp. 287-288; capital and bold emphasis mine)

When responding can someone also share the Arabic of the du'a from the source given?